# I'm clearly missing something... 'ruby' doesn't work but './ruby' does (centos 5.5, installed from source)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, centos

Trying to get a rails server running nicely.

- downloaded ruby 1.8.7 using link from rails page.
- did ./configure/make/install, installed it fine.
- tried ruby -v , got nothing.
- tried ./ruby -v from the folder and it worked.

I feel like i've gone from understanding something about unix, to completely lost. Clearly ruby is working as a 'daemon', but not running as it should. Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Losing too much hair through this process :(

J.

Answer (score 3):

can you see where make install put the ruby executeable?

if you do, check if this dir is in your $PATH by

`echo $PATH`

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Is all that is returned. I've never added anything to PATH before

Comment: usually the command make install will tell you where the executeable will be copied to. try running it again. did you run it with super user privileges?

Comment: --dest-dir="" , and ruby (executable) is in the directory I ran MAKE INSTALL from.

Comment: make install copies the executable to one of the dirs. is dest-dir="" a parameter you specified? if so try running it without this parameter an run make install with super user priveleges

Answer (score 2):

In general, unix needs to know where to find the executable file to be able to run it. It uses $PATH to find this executable file.

So if you type "ruby" it will go look at you $PATH and then look in each of those directories for a file named "ruby". If it can't find it in any of those directories it *should* then also look in the current directory.

So, this whole process will fail if:
a) the directory that contains the executable ruby file is not in any of the directories in $PATH AND
b) the executable is not in the current directory

... one more alternative is that is *is* available in one of these directories... but is not actually marked as being executable by you. You can check this by making sure you're int e directory with the ruby file and typing "ls -l ./ruby"

That will list the ruby file along with all its permissions and who owns it.
It should be something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2010-02-14 10:45 ./ruby
```

Notice the rwx. If your ruby doesn't have x then you'll need to add executable permission using chmod eg: "chmod 755 ./ruby"

Also note the "root root" - that means it's owned by root - in general, this means that only root can run it. In this particular example it has eXecute permission for everyone so everybody can run it, but if you do not have execute permission set like this, then it means that if you are trying to run it as yourself, you won't have permission, and you should either add full permissions or try running it using: "sudo ruby"

However - by the sounds of it - the most likely problem is that you just don't have the ruby executable's directory in your $PATH. You will need to fix this even if you get it running right now - because, in future, you will need to run ruby from directories other than the current one.

You will need to google for instructions on adding things to your $PATH - because it differs depending on your version of linux and your current shell, but it's not very difficult.

Comment: "so only root can run it" -- that's not quite true - as long as the last 'r' and 'x' is there in the permissions, anyone with access to the machine can run it.

Answer (score 1):

Which shell are you running? If tcsh, you may need a "rehash". Otherwise, as leifg says, add the directory containing the ruby executable to your path.

Comment: Currently using bash, Centos 5.5. i'm somewhat new to advanced linux... I've gotten LAMP stacks working fine, this is my first foray into Ruby/Rails etc.